# How to use navigate a frame when loading page from markup?

Tags: c++, xaml, c++-winrt

I have my XAML markup code for a Page `<Page>` written in a file `page.xaml`. I am using `XamlReader::Load()` to read my file - which succeeds. It saves it as a variable `rootPage`.

But the function `Frame::Navigate<T>()` takes a `TypeName` as `T`. I don't have the custom page class, I only have it saved as a variable. So how can I load that page and then navigate to it if the page is written in a XAML textfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of Navigate method needs to be passed as the type of page.  You don't need to create the page instance, you just need to pass the type of page. You can use the [winrt::xaml_typename()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/xaml-typename) helper function to create a TypeName object about the page you want to navigate to. For example:

```
void MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    Frame().Navigate(xaml_typename<page>());
}
```

For more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page).

Comment: But how do I get the page's type if I have not defined it as a class in my app? It is defined in a file.

Comment: It is not feasible to navigate to a page instance which is just defined in a file. You need to create a page class and then navigate it.